# Ehcache Update Element

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, ehcache

Am using the below code to do an update to an element in the cache.

```
Cache cache = manager.getCache("myCache");
cache.put(new Element("k1", "v1"));
//updates "k1"
cache.put(new Element("k1", "v2"));
```

Is this thread safe or do we need to do anything beyond this for thread safety.
Also from a performance perspective, every update results in a new Element. Is this a good approach?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

This is the basic API to update cache entries: do a put for the same key with an updated value.
In order to do this, you indeed need to create a new `Element`.

Regarding the thread safety, Ehcache operations are thread safe by design.

But I am not sure what is your context and requirement for thread safety.

Nothing prevents another thread to update the same key at any time of your processing, including between the two puts.
If you want to guarantee that the second put only updates key `k1` if its value is still `v1`, then you need to have a look at the provided [Compare and Swap Operations](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/consistency-options#compare-and-swap-cache-operations) or at [explicit locking](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/explicitlocking).